# 'CGImageSource' does not have a member named 'takeUnretainedValue'

Tags: swift

A lot of posts on the internet say I can return an unretained image source with the following code:

```
let imageData1 = image.TIFFRepresentation
let source1 = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData1 as CFDataRef, nil).takeUnretainedValue()
let maskRef1 = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source1, UInt(0), nil)
```

However, I get the following compile time error:

```
'CGImageSource' does not have a member named 'takeUnretainedValue'
```

Am I doing something wrong? or has this method been removed in favour of something else?

Answer (score 1):

You only use `takeUnretainedValue` or `takeRetainedValue` when dealing with an unmanaged object (e.g. some function that returns a `Unmanaged<AnyObject>!` or something like that). In this case, this isn't an unmanaged object, so this is not needed.

By the way, when returning a object from a Core Foundation function with `Create` or `Copy` in the name, the ownership of this object has been transferred to you, and you are responsible for releasing it (see the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)). In these cases, you almost always want to use `takeRetainedValue`, so that the memory management of this object is managed automatically by Swift's ARC implementation. If you use `takeUnretainedValue`, you will leak memory unless you manually release the memory associated with this object that was obtained via a method conforming to the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).